# Table will not fill 100% of the Div. Thead, Tbody, Table all fill 100%. td and th won't

Tags: html, css

I've tried everything from other similar questions and nothing is working but I can't get my th's and td's to fill the table width.

The table takes up 100% width of containing div.
Thead takes up 100%.
Tbody takes up 100%.
Tr's take up 100%.

But the 4 th and td columns will only take up about 50% width.

I've set them to 25% as I always thought 4 x 25% would add up to 100% but apparently not in CSS.

I've tried adding display block in different places and tried loads of other things but nothing works.

This is what i did:

```css
.booktable {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  height: 55vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.booktable thead {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
} 

.booktable tbody {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
} 

.booktable tr{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.booktable th{
  width: 25%;
  color: grey;
  padding: 1vh;
  font-size: 2vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}


.booktable td{
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2vh;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<table class="booktable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Group</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Cat</td>
      <td>Group</td>
      <td>Balance</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Been trying display inline-blocks, blocks and position absolutes, relatives, table layouts, removing padding... nothing works.
Even doubling widths to 200% or 50% for td.

Didn't want to ask what must be a really simple answer and I have tried as much as I can but had to ask as I've been trying for hours!

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting all table specific display modes, so that's what's getting you in trouble try this:

```css
.booktable {
  width:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  height: 55vh;
  display: table;
}

.booktable thead {
    width: 100%;
    
} 

.booktable tbody {
  width: 100%;

} 

.booktable tr{
  width: 100%;
  
}

.booktable th{
  width: 25%;
  color: grey;
  padding: 1vh;
  font-size: 2vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}


.booktable td{
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2vh;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
  <table class="booktable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Category</th>
              <th>Group</th>
              <th>Balance</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>Group</td>
              <td>Balance</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set table `width` to `100%` then all `th,td` will adapt `25%` of the total width.

Here is the working example:

```css
.booktable {
  width: 100%
}

.booktable th, .booktable td{
  width: 25%;
  color: grey;
  padding: 1vh;
  font-size: 2vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}


.booktable td{
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2vh;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<table class="booktable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Group</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Cat</td>
      <td>Group</td>
      <td>Balance</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```